# How to re-attach outdoor tiles?

Tags: tile, outdoor

3 tiles (20cm by 30cm == 8in by 12in) fell off the floor on the outside balcony.

The substance (concrete+sand?) that was supposed to cement them to the underlying floor is mostly sand (crumbles in my fingers).

The tiles should be flush with the surviving tiles, so the adhesive I use has to provide a few millimeters of thickness.

**What do I do?**

Should I just clean out the "sand" and fill the space between floor and the tiles with [Construction Adhesive](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07MMF7FHD)?
Should I mix the adhesive with sand (to provide more volume so that the re-attached tiles are level with the old ones)? If rainwater gets under the tiles and freezes in the winter, it will dislodge the tiles again, so I must make sure there is no empty space under the tiles...

Comment: You should go to the tile store asking for assistance on the type of tile you have and the correct material/adhesive and method of tile placement. Depends on the substrate the tile is placed on, there is always a good chance for outdoor tile to pop out due to weathering effects.

Comment: I agree with Ed's answer. In addition, I would suggest you watch a couple of YouTube videos on tiling to get the idea of how it's done. "Back butter" and "notched trowel" and other terms are confusing until you've seen the process, but once you see, they're really quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high sand content sounds like mortar that did not have enough cement in the mix.

Any new bonding procedure you use will fail if you do not remove the sand.

I would use thin set with a modifier (some thinset comes with an acrylic add mix).
The modified thinset is better than standard thinset but either should be used and mortar will be what is needed to match the height.

Construction adhesives will squish out when stepping on the tiles where the sand in the thinset or mortar will provide the spacing similar to the original adhesive.

Make sure to mis the appropriate amount of water,
Back butter the tile or put a layer of thin set on and scrape it off it will leave a residue, this helps bonding.
Put the stuff you scraped off plus some on the floor work it back and forth then use the notched side of the trowel to remove the excess set the tile into the rows of mortar and position firmly pressing to settle the tile.
Repeat with the other tiles. When dry add grout some outside tile jobs actually use mortar as a grout grey in color?
Jet set, if really warm put a old cloth over them and keep it damp for the day the dampness helps the cement in the mortar to hydrate and not crack.